# Kafka producer WARN

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The following warning message observed in Kafka producer logs. I have a callback to notify failures. But didn't see failure logs. Is this WARN can cause a message failures to topic?

```
2020-02-17 10:23:47|[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1]|WARN |[o.a.k.c.producer.internals.Sender.warn(251)]|[Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 2031 on topic-partition queue-1, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> retrying (0 attempts left).

Is saying that the producer is going to retry one final time to send the message

If that fails, I suspect you're going to see another log message, at which point you're losing events due to your network exceptions

Comment: Are there any config to increase the number of attempts. If what you told is true then retry has succeeded. Because I can't see anything log from my failure callback.

Comment: Refer `retries` producer property